# CSS3 Responsive Layout - which method can i select?

Tags: jquery, css

HI i am making a website, this website having 3 different mockup for Desktop, tablets, Smartphones.. i can identifying the width using respond.js.

But i question is how can i switch the design to appropriate devices. i can change the width and height using query selectors, but how can i change the content of the page..

any good idea. In earlier i downloaded all contents and used to hide the unwanted content using display:none, i know this is wrong. which is the best way, apart from finding using server-side code?

thanks

Comment: [CSS Media](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps) [Queries](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/responsive-design-and-css3-media-queries/60) does exactly what you're looking for with no JS needed.

Answer (score 0):

Create design themes for all your mockup types and use the same css classes in your markup. Check the window size client side and based on the window side load the appropriate theme.

Comment: you mean, content shuffling, using js?

Comment: I mean that in my opinion you should load a css file with JS after your client side found out which mockup theme is applicable. JS should load the correct design theme then. A design theme is usually a set of CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is wise to detect a mobile browser user agent string (server side) and display content accordingly.

If you are building using PHP, then check out this [awesome](http://www.russellbeattie.com/blog/mobile-browser-detection-in-php) script.

Usage is something like this:

```
if($isMobile){
   header('Location: http://m.youdomain.com/' . urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
   exit();
}
```

Also check out the [Switcher](http://www.passani.it/switcher/)